# Getting context menu and checkboxes to work with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I have an onClick event for checkboxes in a table---clicking on a box appends the checkbox's text to a separate div (a "Favorites List").

However, I also have a context menu and one of its selection options "Set as Favorite" does not do the same thing. I have a named `faveFunc` that was created for using the function on both the checkboxes and the context menu, but something's wrong where I haven't been able to get the latter to work.

Based on my code I *believe* that the functionality of both should be the same, but I haven't had any luck. So I'm wondering if there problem lies with the context menu itself rather than the favoriting function. Any thoughts?

[JSFiddle](http://live.datatables.net/najolumu/1/) (doesn't properly show JSON data. Will see if I can hard code table data into it)

#### Context menu JS:

```
   $('#km-table-id > tbody > tr').on('click', function(e){
     console.log('clicked', this); // works on left click
    })

    ///// Show menu /////
    $("#km-table-id").on("contextmenu", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    $(".custom-menu")
    .show()
    .css({ top: evt.pageY, left: evt.pageX });

    ///// Close menu /////
      $("#km-table-id").on("mousedown", function(evt) {

        if (!$(evt.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
          $(".custom-menu").hide(50);
        }
      }) 

     console.log("click detected"); // works on right click

    });
```

#### My Favorites functionality:

```
function faveFunc(evt) {
    var anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
    switch($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length)
    {
      case 0:
        $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
        break;
      default:
        $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
        break;
    }
  }; // ------------ faveFunc

function newList() {
    let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
     let outputList = $(".populate-faves");

     $(".populate-faves").html("");

    $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
      let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
      let itemText = $(data, el);

      if(fave.prop("checked")) {
        outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
      }
    });
  };

$(".checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc);

$("#add-id").on("click", faveFunc);
```

#### Context Menu HTML:

```
 <ul class="custom-menu">
    <li data-action="open" id="open-id">Open Document</li>
    <li data-action="add" id="add-id">Set As Favorite</li>
    <li data-action="email">Email Document</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle for the question

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/najolumu/1/ Due to the local JSON file I've never been able to render the table with the information properly.

Comment: the fiddle is not working

Comment: That's what I meant, I haven't been able to render the table due to the local JSON file. I'll see if I can hard code a few lines of data into the table.

Comment: creae josn value inside the js, and use that variable